# $\mathbb{Z}_+ \times [0,1)$ in the dictionary order topology $\text{is a linear continuum}$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I want to prove $\mathbb{Z}_+ \times [0,1)$ in the dictionary order topology $\text{is a linear continuum}$.

My ATTEMPT:

Let  $(n, x)$ and $(n^\prime, x^\prime)$ be two elements of $\mathbb{Z}_+ \times [0,1)$  such that $(n, x)< (n^\prime, x^\prime)$. If $n =n^\prime$, then $x<x^\prime$, so $$(n,x)<(n, \frac{x+x^\prime}{2})<(n^\prime, x^\prime).$$ If $n<n^\prime$, then $$(n,x)< (n, \frac{x+1}{2})< (n^\prime,x^\prime).$$  Now we will prove the least upper bound property. Suppose $A$ is a bounded above  subset of  $\mathbb{Z}_+ \times [0,1)$.  If  $(n,x)$ is an upper bound for $A$, then $n$  is an upper bound for $\pi_1 (A)$. Thus the set of all upper bounds  of  $\pi_1 (A)$ is a nonempty set of positive integers and has a smallest element $n_0$. Therefore, $n_0 = \text{sup } \pi_1 (A)$. Consider two cases.

1. If $n_0 \in \pi_1 (A)$, then the set $\pi_2 ((\{x_0\} \times [0,1]) \cap A)$ is being a non-empty, bounded above subset of $[0,1)$, so has a least upper bound $x_0$, i.e. $x_0 = \text{sup }  (\pi_2 ((\{x_0\} \times [0,1]) \cap A))$. If $x_0 <1$, then $(n_0, x_0)$ is the least upper bound. If $x_0 = 1$, then $(n_0+1,0)$ is the least upper bound.
2. If $n_0 \in \pi_1 (A)$ then $(n_0, 0)$ is the least upper bound of $A$.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Consider the set $A = \{(1,1-\frac{1}{2^n})\}$ for natural $n$. What is the least upper bound?

Answer (score 1):

The space is order isomorphic to $[0, +\infty) \subseteq \Bbb R$ by mapping $(n,x)$ to $n+x$ (assuming $\Bbb Z^+$ starts at $0$, if at $1$ use $[1,+\infty)$ instead) And that space is a continuum as an order convex subset of $\Bbb R$. QED.